# display date and time in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

template.html

```
{{incident.created_date_time}}
```

This is ahowing the date and time as `June 26, 2013, 5:42 p.m.` ,how to show it in `June 26  2013 at 5:42 P.M.`.

How to use template filter to convert the date and time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django builtin template filter won't really do this exact formatting for you but a close second using it would be

```
{{ incident.created_date_time|:"F j Y P" }}
```

Otherwise you would have to create your own date filter.

```
@register.filter(name='myDate')
def myDate(value, arg):
    #arg is optional and not needed but you could supply your own formatting if you want.
    dateformatted = value.strftime("%b %d, %Y at %I:%M %p")
    return dateformatted
```

This requires the `incident.created_date_time` to be a `datetime` object.

and then you'd use it like

```
{{ incident.created_date_time|myDate }}
```

Comment: should i write this filter in views or in templatetage.py

Comment: in the same file you store the rest of your custom template tags or filters, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Comment: I copied the filter code in templatetages.py and it is giving this error "Invalid filter: 'myDate'"

Comment: Did you load it? `{% load templatetages %}`. Did you follow the exact layout of the template tag file?

Comment: yes i followed the rule and i loaded the tag {% load templatetages %} at the html where i am using date format

Comment: Ah, yeah, remove `arg` from the filter definition as the comment says below "it's optional" and I included it for show.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{{ incident|date:"F d Y P" }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Edit:
No if you want to have at in date you need to write your own date filter.

Look at limelights post.

Comment: Sry my mistake there should be 'date' not data

Comment: i tried your code between date and time i need to place "at" is it possible to do here

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it "app-wide" by setting DATE_FORMAT or DATETIME_FORMAT to your settings.py.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#date-format